# Preguntar por la página actual

Tags: django

Estoy remarcando un tag `<li>` cuando estoy en la página que este señala, lo estoy solucionando con el siguiente algoritmo:

```
<li {% if request.path == "/" %} class="active" {% endif %}>Home</li>
<li {% if request.path == "/temas/" %} class="active" {% endif %}>Temas</li>
<li {% if request.path == "/contactos/" %} class="active" {% endif %}>Contactos</li>
```

El problema de esta solución es que es poco escalable, cada vez que se cambie alguna URL hay que modificar el código del html. Por eso quería saber si se hay alguna manera de hacer:

```
<li {% if request.path == "{% url 'temas' %}" %} class="active" {% endif %}>Temas</li>
```

Ya que, lamentablemente, esta última forma no es válida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné de la siguiente forma:

```
{% url 'temas' as temas_url %}
...
<li class="{% if request.path == temas_url %}active{% endif %}">
```